# Swift - display UICollectionView after retrieving data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionView` that I fill by retrieving data from my Firestore Database. My problem is that I would like retrieve the data and only after finishing that the `collectionView` should appear with an animation being handled inside `willDisplay`.

This is how I retrieve my data:

```
func getWishlists() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").order(by: "listIDX").getDocuments() { ( querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }else {
            // get all documents from "wishlists"-collection and save attributes
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let documentData = document.data()
                let listName = documentData["name"]
                let listImageIDX = documentData["imageIDX"]

                // if-case for Main Wishlist
                if listImageIDX as? Int == nil {
                    self.dataSourceArray.append(Wishlist(name: listName as! String, image: UIImage(named: "iconRoundedImage")!, wishData: [Wish](), color: self.mainColor))
                    // set the drop down menu's options
                    self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownOptions.append(listName as! String)
                    self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownListImages.append(UIImage(named: "iconRoundedImage")!)
                }else {

                    self.dataSourceArray.append(Wishlist(name: listName as! String, image: self.images[listImageIDX as! Int], wishData: [Wish](), color: self.customColors[listImageIDX as! Int]))

                    self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownOptions.append(listName as! String)
                    self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownListImages.append(self.images[listImageIDX as! Int])
                }

                // reload collectionView and tableView
                self.theCollectionView.reloadData()
                self.dropDownButton.dropView.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
        self.getWishes()
    }
}
```

I call `getWishlists` inside my `viewDidLoad` and this is how I handle my `collectionView`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // return 1 more than our data array (the extra one will be the "add item" cell)
    return dataSourceArray.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // if indexPath.item is less than data count, return a "Content" cell
    if indexPath.item < dataSourceArray.count {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell
        // set cell label
        cell.cellLabel.text = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].name
        // set cell image
        cell.wishlistImage.image = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].image          
        // set background color
        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].color
        cell.wishCounterView.backgroundColor = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].color
        cell.priceView.backgroundColor = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].color



        cell.customWishlistTapCallback = {

            let heroID = "wishlistImageIDX\(indexPath)"
            cell.theView.heroID = heroID

            let addButtonHeroID = "addWishButtonID"
            self.addButton.heroID = addButtonHeroID     

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WishlistVC") as! WishlistViewController            

            vc.theTableView.tableView.reloadData()
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        return cell
    }

    // past the end of the data count, so return an "Add Item" cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddItemCell", for: indexPath) as! AddItemCell

    // set the closure
    cell.tapCallback = {

        self.listNameTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()

        // let newListView appear
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.blurrImage.alpha = 0.96
            self.blurrImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            self.newListView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

        self.appWillEnterForegroundHandler()

    }

    return cell

}

// animate displaying cells
func collectionView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Add animations here
    cell.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.5,
        delay: 0.05 * Double(indexPath.row),
        animations: {
            cell.alpha = 1
    }) 
}
```

At the moment the cells are not being animated, instead they are just being displayed after a little bit of time when the data is retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

willDisplay is the correct place to pul the animation; however it only fires if you set the delegate.  It looks like you se the datasource or you wouldn't see anything.  Set the delegate and breakpoint willDisplay to verify its being called.

Comment: what delegate do I have to add? I tested it with a `print` inside `willDisplay` but it is not being called

Comment: UICollectionViewDelegate as in: collectionView.delegate=self

Comment: ah right. It is actually animation properly now. However there is still a little problem. If you look at the code, the last `cell` inside the `collectionView` is a `addItemCell` and that `cell` doesn't have any retrieved data so it is there at the beginning. Is there a way to only show the whole `collectoinView` until all the data is received ?

Comment: yes just set `collectionView.isHidden = true` and when your request comes back and its non empty  set `collectionView.isHidden = false`

Comment: yep that is working perfectly fine :) Just figured that out myself, thanks!

Comment: ok.. Actually one last thing. At the moment if I scroll down and up again the `cells` are being animated again. But I would like to animate them only the first time. Do you maybe know how to fix that as well ? :)

Comment: make a flag like `shouldAnimateCells = true` and add a `guard shouldAnimate else {return}` to your willDisplay method,  then in the delegate method `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, set it to false if you have data (ie if they scroll an empty view don't set the flag).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205891/discussion-between-chris-and-josh-homann).